# I’m asking about how to know signal is even or odd??? And I want to know how to understand and analysis conveltion signal

Tags: signal-analysis

Even and odd signals , and impulse testing like convolution signals

Answer (score 1):

Even (real) signal

$$ x(t) = x(-t) $$
$$ x[n] = x[-n] $$

for DFT convention of (periodic) signals defined on $0 \leq n \leq N-1 $ also
$$ x[n] = x[N-n] $$

Odd (real) signals
$$ x(t) = - x(-t) $$
$$ x[n] = - x[-n] $$

for DFT convention of (periodic) signals defined on $0 \leq n \leq N-1 $ also
$$ x[n] = - x[N-n] $$

for complex signals, replace rhs with conjugates; to define conjugate-symmetric and conjugate antisymmetric parts...